How to alternate automatically at boot between my laptop's two installed OSes?
I have Windows 10 and Ubuntu Linux 20.04 installed into separate encrypted partitions on my Dell Latitude 5411 laptop. When I shut down one OS, it's always to boot into the other one.
Linux is the default, so currently when I need to boot into Windows, I hit F12 and select it from the UEFI boot menu.
Is there a way to get the laptop to always select the "other" boot option each time I reboot ?
I'd like to avoid always booting into GRUB, and then selecting Windows from there, because as far as I remember it prevented the Bitlocker encryption from unlocking my Windows partition.

"I'd like to avoid always booting into GRUB" - You cannot avoid this step.  GRUB is the reason you can even make the choice between Linux and Windows.  BitLocker should be compatible with GRUB. I would just avoid the dual boot situation entirely and accomplish everything with WSL. You should be able to change which GRUB entry is selected by default.

See if this answer helps.

@harrymc: thanks, I'll try setting the default entry in UEFI to be Windows, and adding a startup command so after each boot into Windows it sets the next boot to Linux.

Setting BootNext from Windows didn't work, but setting it from Linux worked. I'm already enjoying this new hands off boot, it's like UEFI can read my mind!
